# AnimatedVectorDrawable not in start state

Tags: android, android-animation, android-vectordrawable

I have an activity with custom ImageView and a button that opens a new instance of the same activity. Click on ImageView starts an animation of AnimatedVectorDrawable.

The problem is that if I play an animation in the first activity, it will appear in the next activities in its end state. This won't happen if I won't play an animation in first activity or if I use regular ImageView.

The problem also doesn't occur with AnimatedVectorDrawableCompat in API 19.

What is the reason for this behavior?

Activity:

```
class TestActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    companion object {
        fun start(context: Context){
            context.startActivity(Intent(context, TestActivity::class.java))
        }
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test)

        myImageView.setOnClickListener {
            (myImageView.drawable as? Animatable)?.start()
        }

        button.setOnClickListener {
            TestActivity.start(this)
        }
    }
}
```

Custom ImageView:

```
class MyImageView (context: Context, attrs: AttributeSet?) : ImageView(context, attrs) {

    init {
        val anim = ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, R.drawable.anim)
        setImageDrawable(anim)
    }
}
```

Animation resource:

```
<animated-vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:aapt="http://schemas.android.com/aapt" >
    <aapt:attr name="android:drawable">
        <vector
            android:width="24dp"
            android:height="24dp"
            android:viewportWidth="24.0"
            android:viewportHeight="24.0">
            <path
                android:name="path"
                android:strokeColor="#fff"
                android:strokeWidth="2"
                android:pathData="M 3, 7 L 21, 7 M 3, 12 L 21, 12 M 3, 17 L 21, 17"/>
        </vector>

    </aapt:attr>
    <target android:name="path" >
        <aapt:attr name="android:animation">
            <set android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator">
                <objectAnimator
                    android:duration="200"
                    android:propertyName="pathData"
                    android:valueFrom="M 3, 7 L 21, 7 M 3, 12 L 21, 12 M 3, 17 L 21, 17"
                    android:valueTo="M 5.5, 5.5 L 12,12  M 5.5, 18.5  L 18.5, 5.5 M 12,12 L 18.5, 18.5"
                    android:valueType="pathType"/>
            </set>
        </aapt:attr>
    </target>
</animated-vector>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your custom `ImageView` has to extend `AppCompatImageView`.

This is working fine when using a regular `ImageView` in your layout because AppCompat automatically replace the `ImageView` with an `AppCompatImageView`.

Comment: It doesn't help, but I found out that `setImageResource(R.drawable.anim)` fixes the problem.

Comment: setImageResource(R.drawable.anim) also hepled me in same situation